# How can I rewrite ANY kind of string in htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, routes

I'm working on a simple routing system, and I need to make a RewriteRule where EVERYTHING (no exception is being passed as a query parameter to my main php file.

However, ^(.+)$ and ^(.*)$ do not seem to work. The only thing that's being returned using them is '/index.php'.

The only thing that does seem to work is ^([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*)$, etc., but the thing is: I want this expression to match all Unicode characters, and I assume that an expression which accomplishes this manually would be very slow and inelegant.

So... why do these allegedly obvious expressions not work properly?

Thanks in advance.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @anubhava even the root / URL doesn't work.

Comment: Let me clarify: nothing is being passed over to the 'path' query string parameter, other than 'index.php'. that goes for ANY URL that I try to enter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php?path=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It is because of 2 `RewriteCond` lines above that stop the rule from executing twice which was happening for your rule.  2nd time `REQUEST_URI` becomes `index.php` hence your get `path` parameter as `index.php`